# Retrieve WordPress Database Info and display in form

Tags: database, wordpress

Sorry I am new to WordPress and still having difficulty to retrieve my data from my custom database. So far this is my code for submitting data to my wp_datareg table.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Data-Register
*/
get_header();
?>

<?php
If($_POST['Submit']) {

global $wpdb;

$Data1=$_POST['Data1'];
$Data2=$_POST['Data2'];

if($wpdb->insert(
        'wp_datareg',
        array(
                'Data1' => $Data1,
                'Data2' => $Data2

                )

    ) == false) wp_die('Database Insertion Failed');
    else echo '<h2>Database Insertion Succesful</h2><p />';
?>
<?php
}
else //  else we didn't submit the form so display the form
{
?>
<
<h4>Data Registration Form</h4>
<form action="" method="post" id="addcourse">
<p><label>Put Data1:<input type="text" name="Data1" size="30" /></label></p>
<p><label>Put Data2: <input type="text" name="Data2" size="30" /></label></p>

</div>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" id="addcoursesubmit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

What I want to add is put another text form and search button where user can search a data of Data1 and edit its value on the form, (please see the image)
Sorry for being such a noob.

[PLEASE SEE THIS IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVJdM.jpg)

Thank you.
br

Comment: Please explain more clearly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Sir try to see the image, I want to get a data from my wp_datareg table using a search box and display the result

Comment: I am wondering how we can get data using insert query.

Comment: Sorry if I make it confusing, the insert query or the code above is the one I use to populate my wp_datareg table, Now I want to fetch data back,

Answer (score 0):

We can fetch data from wp_datareg table using this code, however putting back the data to the form is my problem.

```
global $wpdb;
    $result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM wp_datareg" );
    foreach ( $result as $print )   {
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $print->Data1;?></td>
    </tr>
```